# Javascript array refuses to return indexOf even when matching occurs

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

So I've been having the weirdest problem imaginable, I have a javascript array that contains many last names, it is supposed to go through the text and pick out names by cycling through the words it is given and putting them in an indexOf of the array to see if it is non-negative, however, I made a mistake in splitting the array at first, where I split on regex \s, and it had a blank string in between each of the regular strings.
Funny enough that one actually works, but when I fixed it to split on \n, the array was the same (minus the empty strings), however now it refuses to match via the indexOf given the same inputs. I put a breakpoint in the console to check it out myself, but I found the weirdest happenstance that I have yet to come upon (pictures below).

[The initial accident, which oddly works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD4tW.png)

[The fix which somehow doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBGA4.png)

I have a lot of experience coding, but I have no clue what's going on here, please help.

Here's the code for reference

```
function findPeople(text,nameList){
    text=text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, " ");
    text=text.replace(/\s+/gi," ");
    var spliText=text.split(/\s+/gi);
    nameList=nameList.split("|")
    var fnames=nameList[0].split(/\s/gi);
    var lnames=nameList[1].split(/\s/gi);
    console.log(fnames.slice(0,15),lnames.slice(0,15))
    var matches = [];
    for (var i=0;i<spliText.length;i++){
        var word1=spliText[i].toLowerCase();
        try{var word2=spliText[i+1].toLowerCase();}catch(e){word2="NOPE";}
        try{var word3=spliText[i+2].toLowerCase();}catch(e){word3="NOPE";}
        try{var word4=spliText[i+3].toLowerCase();}catch(e){word4="NOPE";}
        if (fnames.indexOf(word1) != -1 && lnames.indexOf(word3) != -1 && word1!=word3 && !/(st|ln|lane|rd|road|dr|blv|cir|way|wy|pass)(?![a-z])/i.test(word4) && matches.indexOf(word1 + " " + word3) == -1){
              matches.push(word1 + " " + word3);
        }else if (fnames.indexOf(word1) != -1 && lnames.indexOf(word2) != -1 && word1!=word2 && !/(st|ln|lane|rd|road|dr|blv|cir|way|wy|pass)(?![a-z])/i.test(word3) && matches.indexOf(word1 + " " + word2) == -1){
              matches.push(word1+" "+word2);
        }else if (fnames.indexOf(word1) != -1 && !/(st|ln|lane|rd|road|dr|blv|cir|way|wy|pass)(?![a-z])/i.test(word2)  && matches.indexOf(word1) == -1){
              matches.push(word1);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `g` flag on all your regular expressions?

Comment: post your array as well.

Comment: the `working fix` and the `non working fix` arrays, I mean to say.

Comment: The g flag is for global, and I want it to match all the instances, and not simply the first

Comment: Those arrays are really big, but you can see a snippet of them in the pictures I showed, it's the first 15 elements.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not seeing a problem

```
var matches1 = findPeople("Brendon K. Smith", "brendon seth|smith gordon");
console.log(JSON.stringify(matches1)); // outputs ["brendon smith"] as expected
var matches2 = findPeople("Brendon Gordon", "brendon seth|smith gordon");
console.log(JSON.stringify(matches2)); // outputs ["brendon gordon"] as expected
var matches3 = findPeople("Seth", "brendon seth|smith gordon");
console.log(JSON.stringify(matches3)); // outputs ["seth"] as expected

function findPeople(text,nameList){
    text=text.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, " ");
    text=text.replace(/\s+/gi," ");
    var spliText=text.split(/\s+/gi);
    nameList=nameList.split("|")
    var fnames=nameList[0].split(/\s/gi);
    var lnames=nameList[1].split(/\s/gi);
    console.log(fnames.slice(0,15),lnames.slice(0,15))

    var matches = [];
    for (var i=0;i<spliText.length;i++){
        var word1=spliText[i].toLowerCase();
        try{var word2=spliText[i+1].toLowerCase();}catch(e){word2="NOPE";}
        try{var word3=spliText[i+2].toLowerCase();}catch(e){word3="NOPE";}
        try{var word4=spliText[i+3].toLowerCase();}catch(e){word4="NOPE";}
        if (fnames.indexOf(word1) != -1 && lnames.indexOf(word3) != -1 && word1!=word3 && !/(st|ln|lane|rd|road|dr|blv|cir|way|wy|pass)(?![a-z])/i.test(word4) && matches.indexOf(word1 + " " + word3) == -1){
              matches.push(word1 + " " + word3);
        }else if (fnames.indexOf(word1) != -1 && lnames.indexOf(word2) != -1 && word1!=word2 && !/(st|ln|lane|rd|road|dr|blv|cir|way|wy|pass)(?![a-z])/i.test(word3) && matches.indexOf(word1 + " " + word2) == -1){
              matches.push(word1+" "+word2);
        }else if (fnames.indexOf(word1) != -1 && !/(st|ln|lane|rd|road|dr|blv|cir|way|wy|pass)(?![a-z])/i.test(word2)  && matches.indexOf(word1) == -1){
              matches.push(word1);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: That would be true in the first case, where I split on /s, but the second one is the one that's not working, wherein I split on \n, so any  \n characters would be stripped out. however, there may be other invisible characters in there, so I think that might be a good guess, and that's what \s was catching and doing the extra splits on.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to make the js display any hidden characters from the command prompt?

Comment: So I checked it using JSON.stringify, and it returned that there are no invisible chars in there.

Comment: Is your concern that the output says lnames[0] == 'smith' is false?

Comment: @JasonTiemann I posted some code in the answer, after running this on JSFiddle, i don't see a problem with it.

Comment: Yes, because lnames 0 is Smith And yes it should run properly, that's why it's so odd that it's not.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved it. For some reason JSON didn't return the hidden character /r, so there was a hidden /r that wasn't getting split out.

Thank you for the help!